# How the Obj C object's property name may go through several calls and become a selector name?

Tags: objective-c

I have a small piece of code using MapBox framework:

```
if (tmpItem.itemTyype > 0 && tmpItem.itemTyype <= 12)
    marker = [[RMMarker alloc] initWithUIImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"PoiSmall%d",tmpItem.itemTyype]]];
else
    marker = [[RMMarker alloc] initWithUIImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"PoiSmall"]];
```

This code leads to an exception:

-[RMQuadTreeNode itemTyype]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xe9aaf00

The RMQuadTreeNode class is a MapBox' class and never be used by myself in my code. Note the unrecognized selector name - this is the name of my tmpItem.itemTyype property!

If I replace this code with the following:

```
if (tmpItem.itemTyype > 0 && tmpItem.itemTyype <= 12)
    image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"PoiSmall%d",tmpItem.itemTyype]];
else
    image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"PoiSmall"];

marker = [[RMMarker alloc] initWithUIImage:image];
```

then error is gone. It's not a problem to replace one fragment of code with another one, but I want to know HOW the 'itemTyype' property became a selector name and later was called somethere inside MapBox framework. The property name went thru NSString call, UIImage call, RMMarker call and do-not-know-how-many another calls to reach RMQuadTreeNode. HOW THIS CAN BE?

This knowledge is not necessary for me to solve this particular problem, but it is necessary to know Objective C better.

**EDIT**. I have to change the question above. Adjusted question is: ***I want to know HOW the 'itemTyype' property was passed not only to [NSString ...] call but also somethere inside MapBox framework***.

In other words, should we see something like

```
-[UIImage itemTyype]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xe9aaf00
```

or

```
-[RMMarker itemTyype]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xe9aaf00
```

?

Answer is NO because the [tmpItem itemTyype] is a parameter of

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"PoiSmall%d",tmpItem.itemTyype]
```

(ok, just rewriting it as)

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"PoiSmall%d",[tmpItem itemTyype]]
```

but it's not a parameter of [UIImage ...] nor [RMMarker ...] nor something else like [RMQuadTreeNode ...].

So how it was passed thru the chain of all these calls above and reached [RMQuadTreeNode ...] call? How the parameter of [NSString ...] call magically turned into a parameter of [RMQuadTreeNode ...] call?

Comment: You have serious problems with the basics - what is a parameter, what is a method, what is a property. And how to use a debugger. Debugger would show you your problem pretty fast.

Comment: @Sulthan Where should I set the checkpoint to?

Comment: @Volker yes, I'm using ARC

Comment: So it might be that in your example the UIImage is relased before it can be used in RMMarker alloc/init method. And it works when you store the image in a variable.

Comment: @Volker According to Apple docs [UIImage imageNamed:] is pointing to the cached object created by the system during first time method invocation, so it will be very strange if it really released. Even more, the exception message should be another one in this case.

Comment: @Volker But I found that sometimes tmpItem is nil. The code above is from the RMMapViewDelegate protocol callback method and should be called each time to create the marker. I found that sometimes it called twice: one with nil passed as tmpItem and another with right object. I think this is a bug in MapBox. So I will check the passed tmpItem for nil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Objective-C dot notation for properties is just a 'shortcut' for writing accessor methods. So when you write

```
object.property
```

This is equivalent to writing:

```
[object property]
```

And

```
object.property = ?
```

is equivalent to:

```
[object setProperty:?]
```

So, back to your example,

```
[[RMMarker alloc] initWithUIImage:… ,tmpItem.itemTyype]]];
```

is the same as:

```
[[RMMarker alloc] initWithUIImage:[UIImage imageNamed:…,[tmpItem itemTyype]]]];
```

This is why you're seeing method `itemTyype` being called.

So object `tmpItem` is an instance of `RMQuadTreeNode`, which doesn't declare method `itemTyype` (or the equivalent property).

These [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html) give a fuller explanation.

Comment: Thank you. You answered "HOW the 'itemTyype' property became a selector name" but the main part of question is "How [tmpItem itemTyype] being parameter of [NSString ...] call was passed out of it thru the calls chain up to [RMQuadTreeNode ...] call".

Comment: P.S. Object tmpItem is NOT an instance of RMQuadTreeNode.

Comment: @mkll You are wrong. The exception is clear - variable `tmpItem` had an instance of `RMQuadTreeNode` inside. That's your bug. Add `NSLog(@"%@", tmpItem)` and check the result.

Comment: I added:
2014-02-23 23:01:15.755 findersway[50219:a0b] <ContentItemObject: 0xd2d9af0>
What should I see here?

Comment: It sounds like `tmpItem` was released before you tried to access the property. Put a breakpoint on the failing line and then try `po tmpItem` in the debugger to see what class it is.

Comment: @AshleyMills It sounds like you are right. I will check it for nil.

Comment: @AshleyMills ..or even better: I will check it for ContentItemObject class that it should be of.

Answer (score 0):

Simple explanation:

If you declare a property setter and getter methods to access this property are generated automatically (different for older Xcode versions) as well as an instance variable for this property. A setter is used to set the value of this variable, a getter is used to get the value, both so KVO can be used as well.

If you declare a property `itemType` like for example

```
@property (strong) NSNumber *itemType;
```

you also get in your class

```
- (void)setItemType:(NSNumber*)newValue;
- (NSNumber*)itemType;
```

as well as a variable

```
NSNumber *_itemType;
```

When you use the dot notation of Objective-C 2.0 like `self.itemType`  these getter/setter methods are actually called.

This is a short overview, you should definitely invest time and read up on Objective-C like for example [this here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html)

Comment: Thank you but my question is not about that.